# DataGrid: почему не заходит в цикл?

Tags: c#

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему может не заходить в цикл - результат пустой. В столбцах буквы, в строке числа, должно проходить шифрование по введенному в textbox слову... ошибок никаких не показывает.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sl = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
                if (col.Name == textBox1.Text[i].ToString())
                    sl += dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[col.Index].Value;

        }
        label1.Text = "Результат: " + sl;
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(2);
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = 1;
    dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Value = 2;
    // и т.д.
}
```

Comment: нет, поясните плиз...
столбцы добавлены были в свойствах таблицы (Правка столбцов)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А каким образом будет истинно условие:

```
if (col.Name == textBox1.Text[i].ToString())
```

`col.Name` и `col.HeaderText` - разные вещи. Скорее всего у Вас `col.Name` равен `column1`, `column2` и так далее, это генерируется автоматически и является именем для использования в коде. А `col.HeaderText` равен `A, B, C` и так далее и является названием столбца для отображения на экране. Используйте `col.HeaderText`.

Comment: спасибо!!! работает, очень помогли!!!
а вот если надо для одной буквы несколько вариантов цифр, то я  добавил в datagrid еще одну строку и для некоторых букв там прописал еще цифру. как сделать условие, чтобы не всегда из первой строки бралось значение?хотя бы идею)

Comment: не совсем понятен вопрос. Приведите пример того что Вам надо

Comment: ну например в заголовке таблицы стоит буква "А", а под ней в первой строке стоит цифра 1. Если мы в textbox введем "А", то пройдясь по циклу нам выдастся цифра 1. А что если в этой же таблице, но уже во второй строке стоит цифра 2...Т.е. "А" может заменяться или на 1, или на 2...как тогда быть?

Comment: тут есть масса вариантов. Все зависит от целей использования программы. Как один из вариантов использовать случайно выбранное число из предложенных вариантов. Результат при вводе "ААА" будет примерно такой "221"

Comment: а как это организовать? поместить random в цикл? а что если как-то добавить условие...?

Comment: можно рандом в цикл, можно условие, а можно и то и другое одновременно. Все зависит от целей